# Google Maps marker not centered

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-api-2

I am using Google Maps to display under a hidden div which toggles on clicking a tab, I have two problems, maybe they are related:

1. the map does not show completely
2. the marker is not centered with in the map, it comes at top left of the map

I am pasting the code, please guide me where I am wrong or any suggestions.

```
    var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById(mapid));
    if( maptype == 'G_NORMAL_MAP' )
    {

        map.setCenter(new GLatLng(startLatitude,startLongitude ), 6);
        map.addControl(new GLargeMapControl());     
    }
    else if( maptype == 'G_SATELLITE_MAP' )
    {
        map.setCenter(new GLatLng(startLatitude,startLongitude ), 18);
        map.addControl(new GLargeMapControl());
        map.setMapType(G_SATELLITE_MAP);
        map.setUIToDefault();
        map.enableRotation();
    }
    else if( maptype == 'G_AERIAL_MAP' )
    {
        map.setCenter(new GLatLng(startLatitude,startLongitude ), 18);
        map.addControl(new GLargeMapControl());
        map.setMapType(G_AERIAL_MAP);
        map.setUIToDefault();
        map.enableRotation();
    }
    else if( maptype == 'G_AERIAL_HYBRID_MAP' )
    {
        map.setCenter(new GLatLng(startLatitude,startLongitude ), 18);
        map.addControl(new GLargeMapControl());
        map.setMapType(G_AERIAL_HYBRID_MAP);
        map.setUIToDefault();
        map.enableRotation();
    }

    // Add 10 markers to the map at random locations
    var bounds = map.getBounds();
    var southWest = bounds.getSouthWest();
    var northEast = bounds.getNorthEast();
    var lngSpan = northEast.lng() - southWest.lng();
    var latSpan = northEast.lat() - southWest.lat();
    var point = new GLatLng(startLatitude, startLongitude);
    map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter());

    map.addOverlay(new GMarker(point));
```

[image: screenshot of the problem]

Comment: Your syntax is API V2, which is deprecated and may stop working anytime. Consider upgrading  to the current version (V3).

Comment: well i cannot at this stage,i have to get this done for now

Answer (score 1):

This code rendering the google map with marker center aligned everytime.

```
        var lattitude = data.getLatitude ;
        var longitude = data.getLongitude;
        var pointLatLong = new google.maps.LatLng(lattitude,longitude);
        var pointOptions = {
            zoom: 10,
            center: pointLatLong,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), pointOptions);
        var pointMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: pointLatLong,
            title: ""
        });
        pointMarker.setMap(map);
        google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, "idle", function () {
            google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
            map.setCenter( pointLatLong );
        });
```

reference: http://www.onlinekurukshetra.com/google-map-not-loading-completely/

Answer (score 0):

Try adding: `position:map.getCenter()` for the marker, so that your marker is centered on the map

Answer (score 0):

Define the size of the map div completely, or use the optional "size" argument to the constructor:

```
map = new GMap2(document.getElementById(mapid),{size:new GSize(510,200)});
```

or run the checkResize() method on the map object after opening the tab

Comment: Can you post a link to a map (or a jsfiddle) that exhibits the problem (or where you tried the above and it didn't work)?

Comment: Don't know what browser you are using, but in chrome it doesn't do anything.  I get a probably unrelated "initialize" is undefined on the body onload call to initialize, then a "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)" from the v2 quota service.  Looks like the key you are using isn't enabled for this domain.

Comment: chromer/firfox 15.0,ie all the same and intialize() is not related to maps,the script is called when the map tab is clicked

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
var zoom = map.getZoom();
var center = map.getCenter();
map.checkResize();
map.setCenter(center,zoom);
```

after you toggle the map div.

Comment: TypeError: map.checkResize is not a function